# data type conversion into SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssis-data-types

I have created one SSIS package from flat file I'm getting one price value.

But in derived table I'm converting the values into `(DT_DECIMAL)` as I need to insert it into database.

My problem is value `12345.6754`. I want to take only 2 digits after the decimal, i.e., I want `12345.67`.

For that I tried `(DT_DECIMAL,2)MYCOLUMN` and `(DT_NUMERIC,10,2) MYCOLUMN` too, but then also it is giving me `12345.6754` :(

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx) I'd look at using an appropriate [String Functions and Other Functions (SSIS Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx) to manipulate the value. In this case, it sounds like you want to[`Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137938.aspx)